# Populating textbox from after selecting value from comboBox

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to populate my textbox after selecting a value from my comboBox.

My code is running fine, I don't have any errors when I run it but when I select a value from my comboBox, it's not populating my textbox. See my code below.

```
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\appointment2.accdb";
    }

    private void Lastname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;


            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string query = "select * from appointments where patientNo = '" + Lastname.Text + "' ";
                command.CommandText = query;

                Firstname.Text = reader["firstName"].ToString();
                patientNum.Text = reader["patientNo"].ToString();
                contactNum.Text = reader["contactNo"].ToString();

            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it looks like you might be comparing a numeric id column to a name patientNo = '" + Lastname.Text + "' which would return 0 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the issue. Had the wrong value to compare my Lastname.Text with and fixed the code's arrangement. Thanks for all your help everyone.

```
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from appointments where lastName = '" + Lastname.Text + "' ";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Firstname.Text = reader["firstName"].ToString();
                patientNum.Text = reader["patientNo"].ToString();
                contactNum.Text = reader["contactNo"].ToString();

            }     

            connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate issues that I see:

- You are populating the `CommandText` property of the `OleDbCommand` object *after* issuing the `ExecuteReader` method, meaning there is no SQL statement being evaluated.

  The SQL statement should be populated *before* the `ExecuteReader` method is issued, i.e.:

  ```
  connection.Open();
  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
  command.Connection = connection;
  command.CommandText = "select * from appointments where patientNo = '" + Lastname.Text + "' ";
  OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
  {
      Firstname.Text = reader["firstName"].ToString();
      patientNum.Text = reader["patientNo"].ToString();
      contactNum.Text = reader["contactNo"].ToString();
  }
  connection.Close();
  ```
- The `where` clause of your SQL statement assumes that `patientNo` contains string data, which could be incorrect given the name of this field.